# PHP does not instantiate the class after including a file containing it

Tags: php, require, autoload

Here is my problem. I have one file (say, func.inc.php) with autoloader function, registered by spl_autoload_register():

```
function autoloaderFnc($class) {
    global $__CONFIG;

    $original = $class_name;
    $class_name = mb_strtolower ( $class_name );

    foreach ( $__CONFIG ['include_dirs'] as $path ) {
        if(file_exists ( $__CONFIG ['root'] . $path . $class_name . '.inc.php' )) {
            require ($__CONFIG ['root'] . $path . $class_name . '.inc.php');

            $classFound = TRUE;
            $foundAt = $__CONFIG ['root'] . $path . $class_name . '.inc.php';
            break;
        }
    }

    if( $classFound ) {
        if ( class_exists( $original ) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
            $error = "PHP User error: Cannot load class <b>$original</b> included at " . $backtrace[1]['file'] . ":" . $backtrace[1]['line'] . " (searching for <i>$class_name.inc.php</i>), but following file was included: $foundAt";
            error_log( $error );

            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
        $error = "PHP User error: Cannot find file with class <b>$original</b> included at " . $backtrace[1]['file'] . ":" . $backtrace[1]['line'] . " (searching for <i>$class_name.model.php</i> and <i>$class_name.inc.php</i>) in none of the following include dirs:<br />" . join ( '<br />', $__CONFIG ['include_dirs'] );
        error_log( $error );
    }

}

spl_autoload_register('autoloaderFnc');
```

Then I have a second file (show_me_poi.php), calling some class:

```
POI::doSmth();
```

Everything seems OK, but sometimes (and only sometimes!) I receive a following error in log:

> [error] PHP User error: Cannot load class **POI** included at /path_to_dir/php/generators/export.generator.php:156 (searching for *poi.inc.php*), but following file was included: /path_to_dir/php/scripts/php/incs/poi.inc.php

This is weird, because class POI is defined in properly included file! And I repeat, this situation happens only sometime (10 out of 100 I think). What can cause such behaviour? And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, and I use PHP 5.2.17-0.dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: And yes, we do use APC. Can it cause this error with PHP 5.2.17? :(

Comment: You should use `class_exists($original, false)` to disable the autoloading when using this function (because you already are in the autoloading function. I'm not sure it'll fix anything, but it will still be better. See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.class-exists.php.

Comment: Do you have enabled all level errors? Is there any error before this one?

Comment: Metthieu, thanks for advice, but it didn't fix it :( Notices are disabled and there are no warning nor errors before that error. Directly after that error there are another one:
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'POI' not found in

Comment: @Matthieu Nope, didn't fixed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to arise only with APC op-cache turned on. I think that __autoload function can't work properly with caches in some cases. AFAIS only some PHP and APC versions are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well and I found a solution for my case.

In my situation I had a custom session handler as well which wrote data to the database when closing the session.

When an error occurred the error handler would fire and the error would be handled normally.
But then the session close handler would run and it would encounter and error when trying to write to the database which caused catch statement to fire which, depending on the type of SQL error would throw an Exception of a certain type, but those classes had to be autoloaded. **At that point (in a session close handler) you can no longer autoload classes apparently.**

Check *when* this is happening. During normal PHP execution, or in some 'special' PHP mode such as a session handler or a while doing error handling?

The solution in my case was to add `class_exists("MyClass", true)` before trying to use it. I could throw a normal Exception instead. The Exception will still 'Fatal' as there is nothing left to catch it, but at least it will show the *real* Exception and not the autoload error.